# How to clone a product to a different website

Tags: magento-1.8, catalog, php, api

I need to write some PHP code in order to enable my collection of products to a new website (same Magento installation).

Here is the small code snippet I have written so far:

```
$_productCollection= Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->addWebsiteFilter(1);

foreach ($_productCollection as $product) {
    // TODO
}
```

I'd like to avoid copying all product properties one by one: I am looking for a **clone** feature instead. Any link to some relevant documentation is also appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the answer provided by @DavidManners is correct, for a large number of products it will take a lot.
This will get you there faster.

```
//get the products
$_productCollection= Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addWebsiteFilter(1);
//get all their ids
$_ids = $_productCollection->getAllIds();
//add them to websites 2 and 3
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_website')->addProducts(array(2, 3), $_ids);
```

Comment: Oh nice didn't know about that catalog/product_website model :-)

Comment: Great solution, thanks. Is it necessary to reindex something?

Comment: @perissf Most probably a reindex is required. Anyway, you should reindex everything after big imports or data changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign products to multiple websites all you need to do is add all the appropriate website ids. You code should look something like.

```
$_productCollection= Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->addWebsiteFilter(1);

foreach ($_productCollection as $product) {
    $product->setWebsiteIds(array(1,2,3));
    $product->save();
}
```

Where `array(1,2,3)` is an array of all the website ids you would like the product on.

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers... thanks anyway!

Comment: No problem Marius has the better one ;)